# PHP Parsing HTML to multidimensional JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am working on parsing HTML and get multidimensional output array as json. 
I am parsing html like I want but I couldn't create JSON array.

The example output of foreach loop:

PS: every json object has different string value.

0:"blahblah"

1:"blahblah"

2:"blahblah"

3:"blahblah"

4:" " // only space

5:"blahblah"

6:"blahblah"

7:"blahblah"

8:"blahblah"

9:" " // only space

...

I want create json array like this:[image]

```
 $output = array();
    $html = str_get_html($ret);

    $lessons["lesson"] =array();
    foreach($html->find('table//tbody//tr') as $element) {

        $temp = strip_tags($element->innertext);

        array_push($lessons['lesson'], $temp); // the objects (I wrote as 'blahblah' every object but I getting different values always)

        if($temp == " ") // if there is only space push array the output and create new array
        {

            array_push($output , $lessons["lesson"]);
            unset($lessons);
            $lessons["lesson"] = array();
        }
    }
echo (json_encode($output ,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)); // $output show nothing
```

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your issue is getting all the blah into the array then the below will get you there. I am not following the code too well but attempt to explain my thoughts in comments.

```
$json = ["blahblah"
,"blahblah"
,"blahblah"
,"blahblah"
," "
,"blahblah"
,"blahblah"
,"blahblah"
,"blahblah"
," "];


$lessons["lesson"] = []; // I think this is the array you are using
$tmp = []; // Something tmp to hold things
foreach($json as $elm){ //Loop what I assume $html->find('table//tbody//tr') is returning
    if($elm != '&nbsp;'){//Wait for a ' ' and add to tmp
        $tmp[] = $elm;
    } else {
         $lessons["lesson"][] = $tmp; // This array is done so keep it and restart
         $tmp = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! bu i changed your if clause as "if($elm != '&nbsp;') then it worked! If you update your post like this, I am gonna accept your answer